# VBA - Exportar dados de uma tabela

Tags: vba, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tento exportar dados de uma tabela online para o Excel e as vezes funciona, mas na maioria aparece o erro em tempo de execução 91 "a variável do objeto ou a variável do bloco with não foi definida".

O código é o seguinte

```
Sub açoes()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

ie.navigate "https://www.clubefii.com.br/proventos-rendimento-distribuicoes-amortizacoes#"
ie.Visible = True

Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
DoEvents
Loop


Cells(2, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innertext
Cells(3, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(18).innertext
Cells(4, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(34).innertext
Cells(5, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(50).innertext
Cells(6, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(66).innertext
Cells(7, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(82).innertext
Cells(8, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(98).innertext
Cells(9, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(114).innertext
Cells(10, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(130).innertext
Cells(11, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(146).innertext
Cells(12, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(162).innertext
Cells(13, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(178).innertext
Cells(14, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(194).innertext
Cells(15, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(210).innertext
Cells(16, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(226).innertext
Cells(17, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(242).innertext
Cells(18, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(258).innertext
Cells(19, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(274).innertext
Cells(20, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(290).innertext
Cells(21, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(306).innertext
Cells(22, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(322).innertext
Cells(23, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(338).innertext
Cells(24, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(354).innertext
Cells(25, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(370).innertext
Cells(26, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(386).innertext
Cells(27, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(402).innertext
Cells(28, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(418).innertext
Cells(29, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(434).innertext

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Olá Sara, seja bem vinda! Por favor, edite a pergunta e insira o código em texto para que outros programadores possam testar seu código.

Comment: Oii, mudei! Mas não está ficando organizado

Comment: Sara, primeiro uma dica: ao apontar erros ou crashes no código, sempre indique a linha em que ele aparece.

Comment: Segundo, eu tenho experiência considerável em data scraping no vba, e acho que sei qual é seu problema. Para o driver do Internet Explorer, o ```READYSTATE_COMPLETE``` não indica que a página acabou de carregar, e sim que os elementos SÍNCRONOS da página acabaram de carregar, mas os assíncronos não necessariamente carregaram. Resultado:frequentemente, quando o navegador está com o READYSTATE_COMPLETE, você carregou o leiaute/template da página, mas os dados ainda estão sendo requisitados e retornados. Por isso, algum ou todos os  ```TD``` que você chama ainda não existem.

Comment: Nesse caso, o elemento ```TD``` não existe quando é chamado, e retorna exatamente esse erro.

Comment: Seu computador às vezes roda porque a Internet deu um pico de velocidade ou os dados estavam em cache e carregaram rápido.

Comment: Há duas formas simples de resolver, ambas imediatamente abaixo da instrução ```Loop```: a mais simples é adicionar uma espera de meio segundo (ou mais, dependendo da velocidade da conexão). A mais complexa, embora mais adequada, é pegar um desses controles carregados assíncronamente que você tem certeza de que aparecerão é fazer um ```Loop``` até eles aparecerem.

Comment: Se precisar de ajuda com o código, amanhã eu digito, pois agora eu estou ao celular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sara, eu tenho experiência considerável em data scrapping no VBA, e acho que sei qual é seu problema.

Para o driver do Internet Explorer, o `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` não indica que a página acabou de carregar, e sim que os elementos SÍNCRONOS da página acabaram de carregar; contudo, os assíncronos não necessariamente carregaram. Eles terão carregado se forem poucos e/ou se sua internet estiver muito rápida (especialmente mais rápida que o desempenho do computador).

Resultado: na maioria das vezes, quando o navegador está com o `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`, você carregou o leiaute/template da página, mas os dados que povoarão o leiaute ainda estão sendo requisitados e serão retornados. Esse processo na maioria das vezes é muito rápido e nós sequer percebemos; outras vezes, conseguimos ver placeholders vazios aguardando dados chegarem.

O ponto central é: quando o navegador bate o `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`, é normal que algum ou todos os TD que você chamou a seguir ainda não existam.

Quando a linha `Cells(2, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innertext` roda sem o elemento TD existir ainda (porque a requisição assíncrona ainda não retornou e demorará alguns centésimos de segundo pra chegar), o elemento `TD` não existirá, e portanto não possui a propriedade `innertext`, retornando o erro de que a variável de objeto não foi definida. Seu computador às vezes roda corretamente porque a Internet deu um pico de velocidade ou os dados estavam em cache e carregaram rápido.

Há duas formas simples de resolver, ambas imediatamente abaixo da instrução Loop: a mais simples é adicionar uma espera de meio segundo (às vezes menos ou mais, dependendo da velocidade da conexão). A mais complexa, embora mais precisa, é pegar um desses controles que carregam assincronamente e que você tem certeza de que aparecerão e fazer um Loop até eles aparecerem.

```
'... etc...

Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
    DoEvents
Loop

' A saída simples é mandar a aplicação esperar
Application.Wait 0.5

Cells(2, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innertext

'... etc ...
```

Tente e diga se funcionou! Se quiser tentar fazer a solução mais complicada, busque algum elemento no DOM que com certeza mudará quando os dados assíncronos carregarem (lembrando que tem que ser um elemento que mude mesmo quando os dados a carregar sejam vazios), e aí é só fazer um loop aguardando esses dados mudarem.

Comment: Nossa deu certo! Muito obrigada.

Só mudei para 

    newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 5
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
Application.Wait waitTime    

Porque estava travando com Application.Wait 0.5.

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar. Você marca como resposta certa? Isso me ajuda com a reputação.